# If $p$ is prime then the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has no proper non-trivial subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $p$ is prime then the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has no proper non-trivial subgroup.
I need to use the theorem that any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

My thoughts:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
Then there's  $a$  $\in H$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is cyclic, $H$ is cyclic by the theorem. So $H =\langle a\rangle$.

From here, what I know is that  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can be generated by any element of it since $p$ is prime.

But I don't know how to prove this part.

Comment: The order of a subgroup is a divisor of the order of the group...

Comment: Do you know Lagrange theorem ?

Comment: There is no need to invoke Lagrange. Express $a$ as the power of some generator, and prove the result using an lcm argument.

Comment: sorry. I don't know Lagrange

Comment: @DonThousand. So in your sentence subgroup is H and the group is $\mathbb{Z}_p$? If p = 5,  H can be {0,2,4}. The order of H is 3 and the order of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is 4.

Comment: @jun $\{0,2,4\}$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_5$. Also the order of $\mathbb Z_5$ is $5$.

Comment: ah you are right. doesn't have inverse. ok.

Comment: what does it mean by divisor? @DonThousand. The order of a subgroup divides the order of the group?

Comment: @jun A divisor is another word for factor, i.e., a number that can be divided into. For example, $1,2,3,6$ are the divisors of $6$.

Comment: @jun, Lagrange Theorem says, the order of any subgroup of a group divide the order of the group. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has order $p$, which is prime, its divisors are $1$ and $p$. Hence there are only two subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, namely $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$, both are trivial subgroup

Comment: Try the contrapositive; that is, show that a nontrivial, proper subgroup of $\Bbb Z_n$ implies that $n$ is composite. (I'm trying to do so myself but it's difficult without using Lagrange's Theorem.)

Comment: @player3236, can you show your lcm argument in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$. By your theorem $H$ is cyclic.

Instead of considering a random $a\in H$, we **choose** $a$ such that it is a generator of $H$, i.e. $\langle a \rangle =H$.

Let $g$ be a generator of $\mathbb Z_p$. Since $a \in \mathbb Z_p$, we can write $a = g^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$.

If $p \mid k$, $a = e$, and $\langle e \rangle = \{e\}$, which is the trivial subgroup.

Suppose $p \nmid k$. We prove that $\langle a \rangle = \mathbb Z_p$ by showing that $\{a, a^2, \dots, a^p\} \subseteq \langle a \rangle$ and $a, a^2, \dots, a^p$ are distinct.

Suppose not. Then $a^i = a^j$ for some $i < j$.

Then $e=a^{j-i}=g^{k(j-i)}$.

This shows that $p \mid k(j-i)$, and by $p \nmid k$ and Euclid's Lemma $p \mid (j-i)$.

But $1 \le j - i \le p - 1$. This is a contradiction.

Hence $a, a^2, \dots, a^p$ are $p$ distinct elements of $\langle a \rangle$.

But $|\mathbb Z_p| = p$ and $|\langle a \rangle|\ge p$. This forces $\mathbb Z_p = \langle a \rangle$.

Therefore $\mathbb Z_p$ contains no non-trivial proper subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is to use Lagrange's theorem, that the order of any subgroup of a finite group divides the order of the group.

Since a prime has no divisors, we are done.

Btw, this shows $\Bbb Z_p$ is *simple*.