# Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of a group $G$. If $|A| = p$, a prime number, then show either $A\cap B = \{e\}$ or $A\subset B$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subgroups of a group $G$. If $|A| = p$, a prime number, then show either $A\cap B = \{e\}$ or $A\subset B$.

Given $|A|=p$, we can say that $A$ is a cyclic group. Also $B$ is a subgroup of $G$. So $e\in A\cap B$. If $A\cap B=e$, then we are done. But if $x\neq e\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, assuming $A$ is not a subset of $B$ and vice-versa. Also $x^{-1}\in A \cap B$. If $y\in A\cap B$, then $y\in A$ and hence $y=a^k\in A,k\in\mathbb {Z}$. So $ A\cap B\subset A$.

I am not getting how to proceed from here. I am not quite getting how to prove it. Also, there may be similar posts concerning the same topic but I am not getting it either.

Comment: $e$ is the identity of $G$, so $e\in A\cap B$, regardless.

Comment: The fact that $A$ is cyclic is sort of incidental, and $A \cap B \subset A$ by the definition of the intersection. Anyway, I would think about how you can use Lagrange's theorem here, using the fact that $A \cap B$ is a subgroup of $A$.

Comment: @Alex Wertheim Well, since $A$ is a cyclic group and $A\cap B$ is a subgroup of $A$ , so we can say $A\cap B $ is also cyclic. Now, $A\cap B\neq <e>$ so, $|A\cap B|=p$ , by Lagrange's theorem.  Hence , we can say, $A=A\cap B$ , so the conclusion follows from here that $A\subset B$, right?...(This is because if $x\in A$ , then $x\in A\cap B$ so, $x\in A $ and $x\in B$ . Thus, if $x\in A$ , we can say, $x\in  B$ , such that $A\subset B$.)

Comment: Considering the subgroup $A\cap B$ of the group $A\simeq\Bbb Z_p$, this answer your question: [If $p$ is prime then the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has no proper non-trivial subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821082/if-p-is-prime-then-the-additive-group-mathbbz-p-has-no-proper-non-trivial)

Answer (score 3):

If the intersection is nontrivial, then $|A\cap B| = p$ due to primality. So $A=A\cap B \subseteq B$.